# iOS - Tesseract - unable to read cube language model Cube ERROR (CubeRecoContext::Create): unable to init CubeRecoContext object

Tags: ios, tesseract

I am trying to make a `Japanese` `OCR` app. I am getting this error while i try to initialize `Tesseract`. Below are my code:

```
if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng+jpn") {
    tesseract.engineMode = .tesseractCubeCombined
    tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = .auto
    tesseract.image = image.g8_blackAndWhite()
    tesseract.recognize()
    textView.text = tesseract.recognizedText
}
```

Finally i figured out that i don't have cube files and i couldn't find searching them on github and other's site . Can anyone give me any link where i can find cube files for other language ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cube files are not available for all language. As i used

```
tesseract.engineMode = .tesseractCubeCombined
```

the above code, it will try to use both cube file and regular `.traineddata` file . To solve this problem , i had to replace the above code as below and add only the `langdata` as `.traineddata` format for the specific language under a folder named `tessdata`

```
tesseract.engineMode = .tesseractOnly
```